# Умножение переменной типа float

Tags: php, переменные

Здравствуйте.
Из таблицы БД MySQL в цикле берутся поочерёдно переменные $old_price типа float. 
Их необходимо умножать на 0,95 (т.е. уменьшить на 5%) и $new_price записывать в другую таблицу, также в поле типа float.

```
$new_price = $old_price*0.95;
```

Всё бы хорошо, но... Почему-то иногда цифра нормально уменьшается на 5%, а иногда просто тупо обнуляется, т.е. $new_price после умножения становится равно 0. В чем может быть проблема?

Огромное спасибо!

Comment: какая цифра обнуляется ?

Comment: Выведите `$new_price` и `$old_price`

Comment: Попробуйте дополнить код проверкой `if (!$new_price) { throw new \Exception('New price is empty'); }` и посмотрите на какой записи и при каких условиях новая цена равна 0.

Comment: и зачем для этой операции вообще пхп использовать?